# Cordova plugin with Cocoapod dependency doesn't build

Tags: ios, cordova, cocoapods, cordova-plugins

I want to create a Cordova wrapper over some native libraries that I want to use in my application. The iOS library is available on CocoaPods, but as soon as I add the framework dependency, the application won't build.

#### Steps to reproduce

Create the plugin skeleton:

```
plugman create --name twinpush --plugin_id twinpush-plugin --plugin_version 1.0 --path twinpush-plugin
cd twinpush-plugin/twinpush
plugman platform add --platform_name ios
plugman platform add --platform_name android
plugman createpackagejson .
```

Add the Cocoapods framework dependency to the iOS target in `plugin.xml`:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file parent="/*" target="config.xml">
        <feature name="twinpush">
            <param name="ios-package" value="twinpush"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>
    <source-file src="src/ios/twinpush.m"/>
    <framework src="TwinPushSDK" type="podspec" spec="2.2.0"/>
</platform>
```

Then, create a new project and add the plugin as dependency:

```
cd ../..
cordova create MyApp com.mycompany.myapp MyApp
cd MyApp
cordova platform add ios
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add ../twinpush-plugin/twinpush --verbose
```

The plugin install is successfull and the log shows how the `TwinPushSDK` pod is being installed, however, trying to run (or build) the project from the command line:

```
cordova run ios
```

Fails with this error:

> Error: Expected "/*", "//", or "{" but "<" found.

Anyone knows what this error means or how can I solve it?

---

#### Update

It seems that manually opening `MyApp/platforms/ios/MyApp.xcworkspace` in Xcode and executing from there works fine, so I'm not sure if there's a problem with the Cordova CLI or if I'm missing any step in the way.

Using Cordova 7.0.1 and cordova-ios 4.4.0

Comment: if you publish the plugin I can try to take a look

Comment: The error can be reproduced with the empty skeleton created by plugman. I've added the steps required to reproduce it.

Comment: This seems a CLI issue, so I've opened a ticket in their JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12919